# Jquery works only on double click

Tags: jquery

I want to show or hide a `div` on click. Problem is that, When I click on `img`, `div` is opened and after clicking outside anywhere, It is disappeared but on double clicking, `div` is opening. Please help out to fix this issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).click(function(e) {
  
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if( !$(e.target).hasClass("header-disableProfileIcon") && $(e.target).parents(".header-user-profile-menu").length === 0 ) 
    {
      $(".header-user-profile-menu").hide();
      $(".header-disableProfileIcon").removeClass("header-enableProfileIcon");
      $(".header-disableProfileIcon").off("dblclick");
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

HTML Code:-

```
<ul class="header-user-profile-menu" id="clickoutsidehide">
    <li>
        <p class="header-profile-pointer"></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="header-username-txt">{{ loggedInUserName }}</p>
        <p class="header-secondary-text">{{ loggedInUserEmail }}</p>
    </li>
    <li class="header-logout-btn ">
        <button class="hb-btn-transparent" (click)="_logoutClickHandler()">LOGOUT</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

img on click:-

```
<img class="header-disableProfileIcon" />
```

Comment: Sorry, for not posting whole code at one time. here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dfzor7m3/

Comment: `(click)="_logoutClickHandler()"` Angular? `hb-btn-transparent` Bootstrap?

Comment: Just edited the fiddle to add jquery support. It seems to hide your content on the first click itself. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: This code is not understandable. Can you please post a [mcve] more like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/k34jpr9c/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.  Specifically, your fiddle (+jquery) hides everything on click - is this intended or not?  It's not clear what's supposed to be clickable / what's supposed to happen when it's clicked / re-clicked / etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    if (
      !$(e.target).hasClass("header-disableProfileIcon") &&
      $(e.target).parents(".header-user-profile-menu").length === 0
    ) {
      $(".header-user-profile-menu").hide();
      $(".header-disableProfileIcon").removeClass(
        "header-enableProfileIcon"
      );
      $(".header-disableProfileIcon").off("dblclick");
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.